# Terminate process tree in PowerShell given a process ID

Tags: powershell

Lets say I run a couple of processes from PowerShell:

```
$p1 = $(Start-Process -PassThru ./example.exe)
$p2 = $(Start-Process -PassThru ./example.exe)
```

`example.exe` is going to spawn a few child processes with the same name.

How do I kill *just* `$p1` and its child processes, without killing `$p2` and its child processes?

Just running `Stop-Process $p1` only kills the parent process `$p1`, leaving it's children running.

All of the answers I seen so far involve killing all of the processes with a certain name, but that will not work here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I couldn't really find a good way to do this, so I wrote a helper function that uses recursion to walk down the process tree:

```
function Kill-Tree {
    Param([int]$ppid)
    Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.ParentProcessId -eq $ppid } | ForEach-Object { Kill-Tree $_.ProcessId }
    Stop-Process -Id $ppid
}
```

To use it, put it somewhere in your PowerShell script, and then just call it like so:

```
Kill-Tree <process_id>
```

Comment: Better PowerShell friendly / approved verb would be `Stop-ProcessTree`.

Comment: This could be simplified without the need for hitting the function over and over. Like this: Stop-Process -Id (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.ParentProcessId -eq $ppid -or $_.ProcessId -eq $ppid }).ProcessId

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was getting an error using the [recursive method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942155/5645656). This is something I came up which uses `taskkill` with the [`/t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill#parameters) parameter. It works well:

```
$p1 = $(Start-Process -PassThru notepad.exe)
taskkill.exe /f /t /PID $p1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone landing here is looking for script to kill a process tree by specifying the name of the parent process, you can use @wheeler's Kill-Tree recursive function like so.

Note: By default, I find myself having to constantly kill eclipse and its child java process. So 'eclipse' is the **default name** of the process tree killed by this script, *killProcTree.ps1*, if a parent process name is not provided via the $procName call parameter:

Powershell script called 'killProcTree.ps1':

```
 
param(
    [string]$procName    = 'eclipse'
)

function Kill-Tree {
    Param([int]$ppid)
    echo "Kill-Tree: killing $ppid ..."
    Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.ParentProcessId -eq $ppid } | ForEach-Object { Kill-Tree $_.ProcessId }
    Stop-Process -Id $ppid
}

[int]$mypid = 0
[string]$myProcessToKill = (Get-Process -Name $procName -ErrorAction 0)

if ($myProcessToKill -eq "") {
    echo "$procName is not running."
} else {
    $mypid = (Get-Process -Name $procName -ErrorAction 0).Id
    echo "The $procName PID is: $mypid"
    if ($mypid -gt 1) {
        echo "Killing $procName and its children..."
        Kill-Tree $mypid
    }
}
echo "Done!"
```

Comment: This code snippet returns an error at line 18 : `Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".`

Comment: Perhaps a difference in versions.  Runs great for me, I suppose if you have on some kind of "strict" settings (other than default settings) with regard to type casting and such, that could be a reason that you need to cast the "Id" returned to an [int] type to avoid the type conversion error.

Comment: Quite a bit late, but I'm guessing that Benoit was searching for a process name that had multiple results (ever use Chrome? try `get-process 'chrome'`, it's kind of gross). A solution would be to do a `ForEach($mypid in $myProcessToKill){Kill-Tree $mypid}`

Comment: Just FYI, all of what you wrote below the function can also be written like this: `Get-Process -Name $procName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{Kill-Tree $_.Id}`

Answer (score -2):

`Start-Process` with `-Passthru` returns a [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) object. This object has an [Id property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.id) which is generated by Windows and is unique.

`Stop-Process` has [multiple signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) One looks for the process by Id, one by Name, and one looks for it by the Process object.

You are using `-Passthru` and capturing the output of `start-process` into `$p1`, so you can just pass that object to Stop-Process.

```
Stop-Process $p1
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, because the child processes are not killed.

Answer (score -2):

I know that this answer comes late... But a simpler way (works with PowerShell 5.1+) to achieve this is:

```
Get-Process -Name "Process Name" | Select-Object -Property Id | ForEach-Object -Process { Stop-Process -Id $_.Id -Force }
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, because the child processes are not killed. Moreover, all "process name" are killed and the OP doesn't want that.

Answer (score -2):

Hi I'm noob and I don't know if that's what you mean but I figured out that if I want to kill a process that is visible in task manager I can do it like that:
(name of the process provided in -> "name of the process" below. I pref live examples so I will present it that way)

```
Get-Process -Name "Battle.net" | kill
```

It kills all process ID's related to that process which contain the name "Battle.net"

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, because the child processes are not killed.