# Powershell taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe /T without killing the developer version with the same .exe name?

Tags: powershell, automation, taskkill

I've got a macro looping with powershell and at the end of a run to clean up it kills and restarts the browser, Standard FireFox version firefox.exe

Using:

```
taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe /T
```

**How can I prevent it from killing the dev version of FireFox too, which has the same executable name?**

EDIT:

I was asked to post the code

Link to the original script from github https://github.com/A9T9/RPA/blob/2501e8cbc504160e2aab89a7e35ece9fcf2873e1/command-line/powershell/run%20one%20macro%20forever.ps1

This script shows how to run a macro "forever"
by checking on the command line return value
and killing/restarting Browser if needed

```
function PlayAndWait ([string]$macro)
{
$timeout_seconds = 300 
$path_downloaddir = "C:\Users\xxxx\ui-logs\" 
$path_autorun_html = "C:\Users\xxxxx\UIVision Powershell Script\ui.vision.html"  

$log = "log_" + $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss) + ".txt" 
$path_log = $path_downloaddir + $log 


$browser = 2
Switch ($browser) {
1 {$cmd = "${env:Program Files(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"; break}
2 {$cmd = "${env:ProgramFiles}\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"; break} #For FIREFOX
}

$arg = """file:///"+ $path_autorun_html + "?macro="+ $macro + "&direct=1&closeRPA=1&closeBrowser=1&savelog="+$log+""""

Start-Process -FilePath $cmd -ArgumentList $arg #Launch the browser and run the macro


$status_runtime = 0
Write-Host  "Log file will show up at " + $path_log
while (!(Test-Path $path_log) -and ($status_runtime -lt $timeout_seconds)) 
{ 
    Write-Host  "Waiting for macro to finish, seconds=" $status_runtime
    Start-Sleep 10
    $status_runtime = $status_runtime + 10 
}



if ($status_runtime -lt $timeout_seconds)
{
    
    $status_text = Get-Content $path_log -First 1    
   
    $status_int = -1     
    If ($status_text -contains "Status=OK") {$status_int = 1}

}
else
{
    $status_text =  "Macro did not complete within the time given:" + $timeout_seconds
    $status_int = -2
}

remove-item $path_log #clean up
return $status_int, $status_text, $status_runtime
}
$testreport = "C:\xxxx\ui-logs\uireport.txt"   

For ($i=0; $i -le 9999; $i++) {    
Write-Host "Loop Number:" $i    
$result = PlayAndWait MyMacro-04-2022  #run the macro

$errortext = $result[1] #Get error text or OK
$runtime = $result[2] #Get runtime
$report = "Loop:" + $i + " Return code: " + $result[0]+ " Macro runtime: "+$runtime+" seconds, Result: "+ $errortext
Write-Host $report
Add-content $testreport -value ($report)    
  
if ($result[0] -ne 1)
    {            
        taskkill /F /IM firefox.exe /T   
        
        $report = "Loop:" + $i + " Firefox closed"
        Add-content $testreport -value ($report)
    }

}
```

Comment: `(Get-Process firefox).CommandLine` might help identify which instance was started with dev mode

Comment: once you have the correct one, you can use `stop-process -id <pid of program>`

Comment: what this means is you can do something like: `get-process | where commandline -match "firefox dev" | stop-process` --- replace "firefox dev" with whatever the dev version uses to start that's unique

Comment: ok i looked further into this, and don't see a commandline option... but there are other identifiers. Such as loaded modules for example. See if the dev one loaded different modules. `get-process firefox | select -expand modules`  another place to look instead of modules is start info and then further in environmentvariables. `(get-process firefox).StartInfo.environmentvariables` - the developer setting might have a unique variable set or different values in them set or possible arguments instead of environmentvariables

Comment: something like `(get-process firefox).startinfo | where arguments -notmatch 'devtools' | stop-process`

Comment: if there are no differences in the startinfo, you can always use starttime `$firefox = get-process firefox | sort starttime` followed with `stop-process ($firefox | select -last ($firefox.length - 1)` this will kill all but the oldest one. (not really viable if it loads more than one exe like chrome or edge do) - but if it can work, you'll always kill the newest loaded copies keeping the dev one alive as it should be the oldest one

Comment: ok i think i found a way `$firefoxID = get-wmiobject win32_process | where processname -match firefox | where commandline -notmach devtools | select -expand processid` followed with `stop-process -id $firefoxID` --- please note "devtools" may not be part of the command line, i'm guessing based on there docs, i don't have firefox on this machine to know for sure

Comment: Thanks for your comments Rob, can't kill by PID as this is an automated script, it needs to keep rebooting and PID's at least as far as the task manger reports are randomly assigned at launch, I manually launched firefox and the first time the main app PID was 12588 and them I did again 2 mnutes later and got 1592 so that's a non starter

Comment: I tried using STOP PROCESS but that doesn;t work as the macro refuses to reconnect to the browser when it relaunches, it needs to be a task kill command I think

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Developer edition is installed in the default directory of "C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"

```
Get-Process Firefox | ?{$_.path -notmatch "dev"} | Stop-Process -Force
```

Alternatively you can use the exe file description field

```
Get-Process Firefox | ?{$(Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.Path).VersionInfo.FileDescription -notmatch "Developer"} | Stop-Process -Force
```

edit: to kill the whole process tree as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55942155/4276928):

```
function Kill-Tree {
    Param([int]$ppid)
    Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Where-Object { $_.ParentProcessId -eq $ppid } | ForEach-Object { Kill-Tree $_.ProcessId }
    Stop-Process -Id $ppid
}
Get-Process Firefox | ?{$(Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.Path).VersionInfo.FileDescription -notmatch "Developer"} | %{Kill-Tree $_.Id}
```

Comment: Unfortuntely this isn;t working, it kills the process, but when it reloads the macro errors out and won't connect back to the browser, so it looks like it needs to be done via task kill, stop process must be doing something that is causing the macro reboot to be bloked from connecting again.

Comment: Could I simply change the browser .exe file name without causing too many running issues?

Comment: I'd suggest there's an error with your macro, can you post your code?

Comment: I've added it sorry it's a bit messy atm, I'll try and clean it up when I get back but I'm running late for somethign important. It told me there was too much code to post as it is in the file so I had to rushly remove comments to lower the amount there, hopefully I didn't remove anything by accident Cheers

Comment: Try with `-Force` appended to the Stop-Process. Maybe there's a background ff process that your macro isn't allowing to close gracefully

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried when it didn't work

Comment: Just had a thought, you're specifying /T in taskkill so you might need to kill the whole process tree. I've updated the answer